# Can true surjection really exist for algebraic functions?

Tags: functions

Quoting a definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function):

> A surjective function is a function whose image is equal to its codomain.

Consider an arbitrary algebraic function that has $\mathbb{R}$ as its codomain. $\mathbb{R}$ contains transcendental numbers, which cannot be roots of algebraic equations.

Then, by contradiction, is it not impossible for an algebraic function to be surjective, since we can always find an arbitrary transcendental that is not in its image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the definition of an [Algebraic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function) from Wikipedia. An algebraic function is just a function which can be written as a root of a polynomial equation. It doesn't mean that an algebraic function only takes on values which are algebraic numbers.

So, for example, $f(x)=x$ is a perfectly fine algebraic function which is also surjective.

Comment: It seems that I did not think my question through thoroughly. Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: And $x-\pi$ is another example, which even has a transcendental root!